# Is it possible to make a TABLE PARAMETER in CR?

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to ask , is that got possible to change the table name just by using the TABLE PARAMETER setting? but the column name consists in the both table are the same.

eg:

table 1(dailyregistration)
table 2(dayreg)
P.S: both table got same column name, just the table name had change to (dayreg)

select * from ????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you mean by TABLE PARAMETER, but it is not possible to use a Crystal parameter as one of the tables in the report's source. You can only achieve this effect by either writing your own application to set the data location to the one you want, or by using a stored procedure containing dynamic SQL and the table name as a parameter.

Comment: i think i get the answer from you. Thank you. 
Because my senior asking me try to research whether the table name can b one of the parameter when i wanna change the table, i can just directly key in the another table name as a parameter and run and to get the other table and it's column data.